# Is it possible to reduce size of type in exponents?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Is there a way to reduce the size of some of the type in exponents? For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn,tbtags]{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
h^{(2)}(kr)&= h^{(1) \ast }(kr) \\
\vec \nabla h^{(1)}_\ell (k r ) &= k\, {h^{(1)\, \prime}_\ell} (k r )\hat r
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of above code]

The asterisk and the prime on the right are overwhelmed by the (1).  I could use math workarounds, like placing the functions in large parentheses with the accents outside, or invent new notation for h^(1), but it seems like a typographical solution should be possible.

Comment: `\def\sm(#1){{\scriptscriptstyle(#1)}}` and then use `h_{\ell}^{\sm(1)\,\prime}`?

Comment: Thank you!  Some combination of this answer and the other will work, I think.  I want to match the symbols to the rest of the text.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest increasing the sizes of * and ' instead, and using \raisebox to adjust their placement. Also, using `\vv` from `esvect` wil give you nicer vector arrows than `\vec`:
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[fleqn,tbtags]{amsmath}
    \usepackage{esvect}

```
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
h^{(2)}(kr)&= h^{(1) \raisebox{0.1ex}{$ \textstyle\ast $}} (kr) \\
\vv\nabla h^{(1)}_\ell (k r ) &= k\, h^{(1)\raisebox{-0.55ex}{$ \textstyle' $}}_\ell (k r )\hat r
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  Some combination of this answer and the one in the comments will work, I think.  I want to match the symbols to the rest of the text.